# is it needed to assign undefined to a variable to improve garbage recycling

Tags: typescript

```
let _bus: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter()
// after use
_bus = undefined
```

After use, I want to assign `undefined` to `_bus` to improve garbage recycling.

However, I got an error:

```
 Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type EventEmitter.ts(2322)
```

So, is it really needed to do this?